# I-net clear report's 17 Engine class setData is not keeping the data argument's sort order

Tags: java, crystal-reports

Version: Inet:ClearReports:17

I have a report that works perfectly using i-net designer. The data comes in order for two groups within the report. The purpose is to show counts of data by each user. The first group is a user id and the second group is another id within the data. The second group does have duplicate rows per id and so a summary field is used for a unique count.

However, it doesn't work in the i-net clear API. In my java code the order of the data is what I expect.

```
{
    {"User1", "0104850309", ...},
    {"User1", "CLM_GL_2017_00002", ...},
    {"User2", "CLM_GL_2017_00003", ...},
    {"User2", "CLM_WC_2017_00001", ...},
    ....
}
```

Also, debugging the com.inet.report.Engine setData function I see the data argument has the correct order.

Somewhere in the depths of the i-net clear API the order is lost. The report ends up with both user and record id out of order. It is displayed out with this order on the report:

```
{

    {"User2", "CLM_GL_2017_00003", ...},
    {"User1", "0104850309", ...},
    {"User2", "CLM_WC_2017_00001", ...},
    {"User1", "CLM_GL_2017_00002", ...},
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here. There was a bug in the code where the fields were different when rendering the report in I-net Designer and using their API. The bug was that a column was in the data sent to the API that was not in the I-net designer's report query. This cause the first group's grouping to be ordered wrong.